# Making a grid for a real world design

Tags: adobe-photoshop, grids, layout

I'm trying to build an art exhibition that fits into a 5x5 meter square. I have rectangular boxes that I want to set up in a pattern. So I want to make a grid that's made out of rectangles on my design. Is there a good way to do that in Photoshop?

Comment: If this has anything to do to print, Indesign would likely be the better app for this. I found a couple example videos on it's grid making, auto-fit and gap adjusting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cue0Pmn1-2Q – https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JogH4Mfc2nI

Comment: Thanks. Watched both of those. But I'm trying to split one picture into a bunch a rectangles so its kind of the opposite.

Comment: Could you post some kind of sketch illustration what you are trying to achieve? And add a few more words. I can understand what you are saying in 2-3 different ways.

Comment: Are you trying to split an image into smaller tiles which are to printed separately? (Illustrator would be good to use for this.) Or do you simply want to draw a grid on top of an image and print it?

Comment: Right, in that case, depending on how fancy you want to get with the grid, maybe: http://posterazor.sourceforge.net can't remember if you can do squares. I can't remember if it has much control over that. It might've been built to only support the size of A4 sheet. In Photoshop, you should probably investigate the Slice tool and know that a rectangle slice can be divided with a few clicks.

Comment: @wolff Sorry, guess I wasn't so clear. I want to draw a grid over a picture I have and then print it out as one picture so that I can use that to build the exhibition row by row out of the rectangular boxes based off of the grid

Comment: can you [edit] your question to add some image example? it's kinda hard to imagine what is the end result you want

Answer (score 0):

Try `View > New Guide Layout` from the menu.

Comment: Will that show up if a save the image? I want to make a layout guide so that I can follow the design box by box

Comment: @Potato Well, no. It'll create guides. But you can then draw lines on the guides which will appear when output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused as to what you are asking. I don't know if you are interested in (1) having one picture that is broken up into cells in a grid with a gutter between cells, (kind of like when you see one image across multiple screens at once) or (2) if you are looking to fill the cells with different images.

In any case, you can use the regular rectangle frame tool and click and drag, but while you're dragging, use the left & right arrow keys to add more cols or up & down arrows to add more rows to your grid. When you let go the mouse, you'll have a bunch of frames (cells) displayed as a grid.

At this point, if you are interested in option (2), you can open the folder with your images and drag them into the separate cells individually.

If you are interested in option (1), you can then (while having the grid of frames all selected) use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> (Windows) to Make Compound Path. You can still move the individual cells around or even resize or delete some to make space for text or whatever.

Then, just load the image you want to use. Copy the image (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) after it loads, then delete it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>). And, select the frame grid and use the paste into command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).
You'll end up with one image distributed across all the cells.